# Unable to send blob from NestJS REST server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nestjs

I've images stored in a SQLite database as `BLOB`. I've a NestJS server connected to the database using [better-sqlite3](https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3) that fetches the `BLOB` images as nodejs `Buffer` correctly.
I want to send the images as `Blob` instead of a NodeJS Buffer. I'm using the following code to convert `Buffer` to `Blob`:
`const imageBlob = new Blob([imageBuffer])`

When I log the `imageBlob`, it has the right size but in the JSON response I'm getting an an empty object. Is this a problem with the nestjs response default serialization which is unable to serialize `Blob` objects?

I tried sending the image as NodeJS `Buffer` directly in the response and it works correctly.

Comment: JSON does not support binary data. If you want to send blob, send it directly instead of putting it in a JSON object. Depending on what library is being used to make requests on the frontend, you may have to specify the response type of the API as blob.


If you must send JSON, you'll have to encode data in a format that works with JSON.

Comment: @AviusX Yeah, but the buffer is converted into an array of integers in the JSON so the blob should also do the same.

Comment: @AviusX Example: Base64 encoding. But the user must beware that while binary data values are stored in a sequence of 8-bits, [Base64 encoding uses 24-bits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which means your data can grow to about 3 times the actual size when encoded to Base64.

Answer (score 0):

> When I log the imageBlob, it has the right size but in the JSON response I'm getting an an empty object. Is this a problem with the nestjs response default serialization which is unable to serialize Blob objects?

No it has nothing to do with NestJs. You are trying to encode Binary data to JSON. The [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) doesn’t include provisions for [Binary data](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object). If NestJs tries to encode your Binary data as JSON, that is the result you get because of the JSON specification.

> I tried sending the image as NodeJS Buffer directly in the response and it works correctly.

Yes it should because you are sending the data as is and NestJs has full support for this.

Comment: As far as I understand, Blob is supposed to be the format for transmitting and storing binary data and Buffer is supposed to be the way to manipulate binary data in the code. I don't understand how the support is contrary to this. Also, the Buffer data is converted into array of integers in the JSON so the blob should also do the same.